# NFSv4 container log: Unable to initialize client recovery tracking! (-22)

Tags: containers, client, nfs, recovery

I have  NFSv4 Server running in a container. On starting the nfs process, dmesg shows the log

"[ 6300.503436] NFSD: attempt to initialize umh client tracking in a container ignored.
[ 6300.504800] NFSD: attempt to initialize legacy client tracking in a container ignored.
[ 6300.506142] NFSD: Unable to initialize client recovery tracking! (-22)"

What does this log mean and how to remove it?

Is it somehow related to nfsdcld?